# While loop only running once in my multi class program

Tags: java, swing, while-loop

In one of my classes that does all the back-end "calculating" my while loop only seems to run once. My code seems to all work and I even get an output, but only after the while loop has only run once. All the inputs for the class come from another class and the output is printed in the same class that the inputs are gotten from. Any extra help would also be appreciated.

```
calculating class code:

package clock;

public class basic {

    static displayFrame outputs = new displayFrame();

    public static String output;

    public static String findDate(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int timeToAdd){

        double yearD = year;
        double leapYear = yearD/4;
        int daysInMonth = 0;
        int daysInYear = 365;
        int casePick = 0;
        int x = 0;

    //Making sure that the number added isn't negative, ones for other inputs MAY come...
    while(x == 0)
    {
    if(Math.abs(timeToAdd) != timeToAdd){
        continue;
    }else{
        x++;
    }

    System.out.println(year);
    System.out.println(month);
    System.out.println(day);
    System.out.println(hour);
    System.out.println(timeToAdd);

    /*Starts the counting loop and for each month value, it will determine how many days are in it
    this will allow for exact measurement.*/
    while(timeToAdd != 0){
        System.out.println(timeToAdd);
        switch(month)
        {
        case 1:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            if(leapYear % 1 == 0){
            daysInYear = 366;
            daysInMonth = 29;
        }else{
            daysInMonth = 28;
        }
        break;
        case 3:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 5:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 6:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 7:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 8:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 9:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 10:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 11:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 12:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        }


        /*Decides whether a year, month, day or hour is left, adds one to its counter,
          and then takes away that amount of time from the hours added that are left*/
        if(timeToAdd >= daysInYear * 24){
            timeToAdd = timeToAdd - (daysInYear * 24);
            year++;
            break;
        }

        if(timeToAdd >= daysInMonth * 24 && timeToAdd < daysInYear * 24){
            timeToAdd =  timeToAdd - (daysInMonth * 24);
            month++;
            break;
        }

        if(timeToAdd >= 24 && timeToAdd < daysInMonth * 24){
            timeToAdd = timeToAdd - 24;
            day++;
            break;
        }

        if(timeToAdd >= 1 && timeToAdd < 24){
            timeToAdd = timeToAdd - 1;
            hour++;
            break;
        }   

    //Makes sure there are never 25 hours, 32 days or 13 months
    if(hour > 24){
        day++;
        hour = 1;
    }

    if(day > daysInMonth){
        month++;
        day = 1;
    }

    if(month > 12){
        year++;
        month = 1;

        System.out.println("The date you have requested is: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " Hour:" + hour);
    }
}   
        output = "The date you have requested is: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " Hour:" + hour;

    }
    System.out.println(timeToAdd);
    return output;
}
}
```

JFrame class code:

```
package clock;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class displayFrame extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static basic out = new basic();

public static int hrsIn;
public static int daysIn;
public static int monthsIn;
public static int yearsIn;
public static int timeAdd;
public static JButton enter;
public static JLabel dayLabel, hourLabel, monthLabel, yearLabel, timeAdded1, newTime;
public static JTextField dayField, hourField, monthField, yearField, timeAdded;
public static JFrame frame;
public static JPanel newTimePanel;
public static String output = basic.findDate(yearsIn, monthsIn, daysIn, hrsIn, timeAdd);


public displayFrame()
{
    super(new BorderLayout());

    enter = new JButton("Okay");

    dayField = new JTextField(20);
    hourField = new JTextField(20);
    monthField = new JTextField(20);
    yearField = new JTextField(20);
    timeAdded = new JTextField(20);


    hourLabel = new JLabel("Hour: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    dayLabel = new JLabel("Day: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    monthLabel = new JLabel("Month: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    yearLabel = new JLabel("Year: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    timeAdded1 = new JLabel("Added: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    newTime = new JLabel(output, JLabel.CENTER);

    JPanel button = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    button.add(enter);

    JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    fieldPane.add(hourField);
    fieldPane.add(dayField);
    fieldPane.add(monthField);
    fieldPane.add(yearField);
    fieldPane.add(timeAdded);

    JPanel newTimePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    newTimePanel.add(newTime);

    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    labels.add(hourLabel);
    labels.add(dayLabel);
    labels.add(monthLabel);
    labels.add(yearLabel);
    labels.add(timeAdded1);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    add(fieldPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    add(labels, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}


private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Clock Adder");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.add(new displayFrame());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            hrsIn = Integer.parseInt(hourField.getText());
            daysIn = Integer.parseInt(dayField.getText());
            monthsIn = Integer.parseInt(monthField.getText());
            yearsIn = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
            timeAdd = Integer.parseInt(timeAdded.getText());
            String result = basic.findDate(yearsIn, monthsIn, daysIn, hrsIn, timeAdd);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, result);
        }
    });
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(output);
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            createAndShowGUI();
            }
        }
    );
}   
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Check the brackets once buddy, They are the biggest fault lines in a programmer's code.

Comment: I'll second @BhargavRao in that your code formatting is not good, and that makes it hard for both you and us to debug your code. Understand that code formatting, especially indentation, is there to make it easy to understand code, not to make it look pretty. As an aside, you've got gross **static** modifier over-use in that code and should get rid of over 90% of your static modification. Java has an OOP foundation to help reduce code complexity and increase code re-use, two things that get thrown to the wayside if you make your code non-OOP with static over-use.

Comment: 240 lines is the smallest amount of code you could reduce this to?

Comment: I would recommend learning how to use the debugger so you can debug issues like this yourself. This is solvable in seconds with stepping through with the debugger.

Comment: Without some of those statics the code doesn't work because they are later referenced in static methods, see bottom of JFrame class

Comment: If you're not going to allow for negative numbers, the simply use `timeToAdd = Math.abs(timeToAdd)` instead of the `while` loop

Comment: @JacksonHaile `displayFrame` and `output` don't need to be `static`, there's no reason `basic` should ever need to reference `displayFrame` and you should always be calculating the date/time, never referencing the `output` value directly...

Comment: Also, make use of an appropriate date/time library like Java 8's `Timer` API or JodaTime :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever you call `break` outside of your `switch` statement, it will immediately exit your while loop.

if you want to go to the beginning of the loop, use `continue` instead.

Comment: There's no break outside switch, it's actually an if-else block there.

Comment: @maremp yes there are. In the if blocks after the switch.

Comment: Yep, I'm stupid, I was trying to use a case structure before with the breaks and accidentally left them there when I replaced it with ifs

Comment: How is that outside switch? the if-else block has properly positioned curly brackets and the break is for the case, it's not outside from what I can understand.

Comment: @maremp Not *that* if block, those *after* the switch.

Comment: Oh @kiheru, I saw that one and I wasn't even paying close attention about what's after switch.